# Programmatically attach an image to a node using Storage API to store image in the Database

Tags: uri, stream-wrappers, files

I am building a site where I need to store encrypted images in the database.

I'm using the module [Storage API](https://drupal.org/project/storage_api) as it [supports saving images to the database](https://drupal.org/node/656702). I modified the db.inc file to just add an encrypt and decrypt function directly before writing to / reading from the DB.

This works perfectly however now I need to programmatically import thousands of photos.

I'm using this code to attach images to nodes:

```
$nid = 100;
$node = node_load($nid);
$image_path = '/var/www/coach/htdocs/photos/test.jpg';  
$file = (object) array(
    'uid' => 1,
    'uri' => $image_path,
    'filemime' => file_get_mimetype($image_path),
    'status' => 1,
    'display' => 1
);
$destination = 'private://';
$file = file_copy($file, $destination, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
$node->field_passport_photo[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = (array) $file;
node_save($node);
```

However the destination here is wrong - I don't want to use the private scheme - I want to save the file to the database using the Storage API.

The documentation says that $destination is "*A string containing the destination that $source should be copied to. This must be a stream wrapper URI.*"

After manually adding an image to a node and inspecting the $form item on the edit form page I can see that the #upload_location of the image is "storage-field-passport-photo://", however just passing this string into file_copy as a destination does not work as a valid file object is not returned.

So, **what is the stream wrapper URI to get the file to be saved to the database?**

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of the stream wrappers implemented by the storage_core_bridge module with the `storage_core_bridge_stream_wrappers()` function:

```
$wrappers = storage_core_bridge_stream_wrappers();
```

The name will correspond to the name of the field in which the image data is stored, so `storage-field-passport-photo://` doesn't exactly sound unreasonable. You can use the above function to check for definite, though.

If it still doesn't work after you've determined the correct stream schema, you've most likely hit a bug, which you can get help for in the module's [issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/storage_api?categories=1).

Answer (score 1):

Though trial and error I've eventually found solution that works.

Clive's solution confirmed I had the correct stream wrapper but it still wasn't working.

I found I needed to add the filename to the end of the stream wrapper to pass into the file_copy function.

So the final code that worked was:

```
$file = file_copy($file, 'storage-field-passport-photo://'.filename, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

This is odd as it is behaving differently to if it was public:// or private:// which don't require the filename.